# Global Transaction support Teradata

Tags: teradata

Does the Teradata CLIv2 supports XA? I have a CLIv2 based program and i need to have the XA functionality with Teradata.

I don't find any article in Teradata describing about this.

Comment: You mean [2 phase commits](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/xrmOxQlXa0ETFi5lPxHJaQ/WBYuWGrrNOM66F8MQdKnLw)?

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it as per XA standard. That means, i should be able to start/enlist to a global transaction, prepare the global transaction, and then commit/rollback it.

Comment: I think i got the necessary details. thanks Andrew